# Django migrations not working from GitHub Actions

Tags: python, django, github, heroku, github-actions

I have the command `heroku run -a ${{ secrets.HEROKU_APP_NAME }} python manage.py migrate` set to run after pushing master to Heroku. It runs without errors (below is it's the output):

```
Running python manage.py migrate on ***... ?
Running python manage.py migrate on ***... done
```

But the migrations don't actually run. What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you execute the migrate command in your localhost? If you don't have any errors in the heroku log, I think the error is not related to heroku!

Comment: @JRichardsz yes; works on local and on dyno `heroku run bash`, but not from the GH action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer in the [Heroku docs](https://help.heroku.com/GDQ74SU2/django-migrations). Essentially, add `release: python manage.py migrate` as the first line in the `Procfile`. It doesn't tell me why it's not working from the GH action, but it gets the job done.

Comment: It's the right way to do it but doesn't answer the question